# Trying assign a value to base class atribute (from the derived class method) causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, inheritance, variable-assignment, derived-class, base-class

I have this base class:

```
class Netpbm {
protected:
  string magicNumber;
  int width;
  int height;
public:
  Netpbm();
  ~Netpbm();

  virtual void dump_data() = 0;
  virtual void read_file(string file_name) = 0;
  virtual void write_file(string file_name) = 0;
  virtual float * toArray() = 0;
};
```

and this is one of the derived classes:

```
class Bitmap : public Netpbm {
private:
  Matrix<int> * pixels;
public:
  Bitmap();
  ~Bitmap();

  void dump_data();
  void read_file(string file_name);
  void write_file(string file_name);

  float * toArray();

  int getWidth();
  int getHeight();
};
```

In the method `read_file`, I am trying assing values to the atributes of the class (either the ones inherited from the base class or the one declared in the derived class):

```
void Bitmap::read_file(string file_name) {
  fstream file;
  file.open(file_name.c_str());

  if (file.is_open()) {
    string line_one, line_two;

    if (getline(file, line_one)) {
      this->magicNumber = line_one;
    }

    if (getline(file, line_two)) {
      stringstream ss(line_two);
      string width, height;

      if(getline(ss, width, ' ')) {
        this->width = stoi(width);
      }

      if(getline(ss, height, ' ')) {
        this->height = stoi(height);
      }
    }

    pixels = new Matrix<int>(width, height);

    for(int i=0; i<height; i++ ) {
      string line_pixels;
      getline(file, line_pixels);
      for (int j=0; j<width; j++) {
        stringstream ss(line_pixels);
        string number;
        getline(ss, number, ' ');
        pixels->set(j, i, stoi(number));
      }
    }

    file.close();
    dump_data();
  }
}
```

the code compiles without errors or warnings, but when I try run it, I got a segmentation fault error. The backtrace command in the debugger (gdb) points the assignment of this string as the source of the error.

I also tried:

1. comment the line `this->magicNumber = line_one;` in the method read_file at the subclass, and this way the method is executed until the end, when the erros happens in this scenario (leaving the class, some destructor is called, causing the isse. but i can´t figure out which one).
2. add some getter and setter methods in the base class (for this atribute `string magicNumber`), but the problem persists, and now the debugger points the source the issue in this added methods.

Anyone can tell what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    bitmap.read_file("letra_jota.pbm");
    Surface * view = new Surface2d("image", bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    view->loop(bitmap.toArray());
  }
  SDL_Quit();
  return 1;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

That's the current `read_file` method. it runs until the end, and when try leave the method to the next instruction, i got the segmentation fault error:

```
void Bitmap::read_file(string file_name) {
  cout << "start read_file" << endl;
  fstream file;
  file.open(file_name.c_str());

  if (file.is_open()) {
    string line_one, line_two, line_pixels;

    if (getline(file, line_one))
      this->magicNumber = new string(line_one);

    if (getline(file, line_two)) {
      string width, height;
      stringstream ss(line_two);

      if(getline(ss, width, ' '))
        this->width = stoi(width);

      if(getline(ss, height, ' '))
        this->height = stoi(height);
    }

    pixels = new Matrix<int>(height, width);

    int line = 0;
    while(getline(file, line_pixels)) {
      string number;
      stringstream ss(line_pixels);
      for(int column=0; column<width; column++)
        if(getline(ss, number, ' ')) pixels->set(line, column, stoi(number));
      line++;
    }

    file.close();
  }

  dump_data();
  cout << "end read_file" << endl;
}
```

current `Netpbm` class:

```
class Netpbm {
protected:
  string * magicNumber;
  int width;
  int height;
public:
  Netpbm();
  ~Netpbm();

  virtual void dump_data() = 0;
  virtual void read_file(string file_name) = 0;
  virtual void write_file(string file_name) = 0;
  virtual float * toArray() = 0;
};
```

implementation:

```
#include "netpbm.h"

Netpbm::Netpbm() {
  cout << "constructor Netpbm" << endl;
  this->magicNumber = NULL;
}

Netpbm::~Netpbm() {
  cout << "destructor Netpbm" << endl;
  delete this->magicNumber;
}
```

Comment: “…Assignment of this string…” Which string?

Comment: `string magicNumber`

Comment: Have you tried replacing that assignment with a string constant? I.e `magicnumber = “testing”`

Comment: yes, the same error happens

Comment: I don’t think the error is going to be in the code you posted. I’d be more interested in how you are instanciating the class and calling the method on it.

Comment: this two classes are part of a library (`*.so`), and the class `Bitmap` is instanciated in the `main" added to the question.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think what you’re running into is a C++ abi issue. That is to say, std::string is not guaranteed to be compatible between different compilations. Do you know if this .so was compiled exactly the same as your code?

Comment: yes, both the library and the main program are being developed by me, and are build in the same machine with the same compiler (gcc (GCC) 11.2.0)

Comment: I also tried comment the line `this->magicNumber = line_one;` in the method `read_file` at the subclass, and this way the method is executed until the end, when the erros happens in this scenario (leaving the class, some destructor is called, causing the isse. but i can´t figure out which one).

Comment: And tried add getter and setter methods for the atribute `string magicNumber` in the base class, calling them in the subclasses. In this scenario, the problem persists, and now the debugger points the source of the erro in this added methods.

Comment: You have no error handling. If any of the `if (getline ...)` statements fail, you happily continue with the execution. You should make sure that width and height are properly set when you call `new`.

Comment: I checked in the debugger, and the `getline` is not failling (the variable `line_one`is getting the correct value read from the file).